# Display 50,000 cities in dropdown list in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are displaying all the US cities in the dropdown list. But when i scroll down the dropdown and select some value, then browser gets hanged up. Please let me know if there is any solution to fix it.

```
<div class="customselectdiv custom-req" id="divCity" runat="server" visible="false">
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" TabIndex="10" class="customselect required"     Visible="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

And the cities are binding the dropdown from the database.

Comment: Do you consider this easy to use? Are you absolutely 100% sure that you can't go for a different approach - like a textfield with autocomplete suggestions?

Comment: There is absolutely no excuse for what you are doing... please stop... there are many ways how to do it better... (e.g. jeroens comment)

Comment: Nobody got time to scroll 50k records!

Comment: This is the requirement by the client that i need to fulfill. Cannot we use virtual scrolling in dropdown to impelement this functionality? Please suggest

Comment: If that's really what you want, there are lots of options if you just Google `virtual scrolling`.  Try one out and ask a question if it doesn't work.

Comment: _"This is the requirement by the client that i need to fulfill"_ - tell the client they're wrong or accept that you misinterpreted that requirement.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge (feel free to correct me, guys) there is no way to do virtual scrolling in a DropDownList in ASP.NET. There just plain isn't.  You can get something that looks similar to a DropDownList, for which people have given you links in answers, but 50,000 of anything in a web page is going to be an error-prone memory hog.  And it will hang.

Comment: Ok thanku all for your comments, i will try to change the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to add 50000 records to that select box, I'd recommend looking into a city autocomplete like the one [Google offers](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete?hl=nl).

Answer (score 8):

There is no way for a browser's `SELECT` control to handle 50,000 items. There is no way for a user's screen to handle 50,000 items.

You will have to create your own custom html control. I suggest something like what [wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/) does. Create a search box, and have the *"drop down"* appear that shows 10 items that contain the entered text anywhere:

[image]

But to answer your actual question:

> No, there is no way to fix it. [The web-site is not supposed to be presenting the user with 50,000 drop-down items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx).

Comment: +1 I like this: _"then your user interface design is in serious need of rethought, because you just created a usability nightmare."_

Comment: this is also bad advice when you have big collections. What if I have 1000 items which are similar but I don't remember the exact name ? The wanted result will never be seen. This not fully answered question but ok, this is a little part of the solution.

Comment: I would use this solution in conjunction with a filtered search; depending on country, start by narrowing down by region/county/state.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap dopdown in your appication bootstrap provide search functionality.

I have created dropdown with searcch using bootstrap you can use it.

follow below link, here i have provided example of dropdown.

[Dropdown List with search](http://sharmanish.blogspot.in/2014/08/how-to-create-dropdownlist-with-filter.html)